# How to allow TCP connections from local host only

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, tcpserver

I want to be able to get request on a specific port only from localhost (both from `127.0.0.1` and `my_local_ip`);

I tried the following:

```
int localhost = (127 << 24) + 1; // 127.0.0.1     
sock_address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(localhost);
```

This lets me connect only with `127.0.0.1` but not from the actual local ip.
I also tried:

```
char hostName[128] = "";
struct hostent     *pHost        = 0;
gethostname(hostName, sizeof(hostName));
pHost = gethostbyname(hostName);
memcpy(&sock_address.sin_addr, pHost->h_addr_list[0], pHost->h_length);
```

By that I wasnt able to connect with `127.0.0.1`, I was able to connect with local ip, but remote requests were also answered

What am I doing wrong? Is there any other way?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "the actual IP"?! Your machine can have many interfaces, and each interface can have many IP addresses. In fact, 127.0.0.1 *is* one of the addresses of one of your interfaces. It's just as much your "actual IP" as any other of your addresses.

Comment: Thanks @Kerrek SB - ok, what I mean is that I want to be able to accept request on any interface on my machine but only from my machine, and block remote connections

Comment: Well, enumerate all your interfaces and enumerate each address of each interface -- then check if the desired address is among those.

Comment: isnt there a simple of doing it in code ?

Comment: Simple? Probably. Concise? Probably not so much :-) Maybe [this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html) is a start...

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to change the requirements and just accept connections from 127.0.0.1?  This address was made to have local connections.  This way, you already have a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your application you can only set to which interfaces the port will be bound. In the first case you bound it to the loopback interface (`lo`, IP address `127.0.0.1`) and that means that only you can connect to it because only your own host reaches that interface. If you bind the port to an external interface, `eth0` with IP address `10.1.2.3` for example, external hosts might be able to connect to that port if no firewall blocks the connection request.

The only way to do what you want is by setting up the packet filter (firewall) of your local machine to deny/drop connection requests (SYN packets) to that specific port incoming from IP addresses that are not recognized as your own. In this case the remote host would think that your TCP port is closed or blocked, depending on how you set the filter.

Well... you could also accept any connection from any interface and instantly close it if the remote host is not one of your own IP addresses, but for some reason I guess that's what you really want.