# Why Spark UI is started at 10.184.140.204:4040?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, apache-spark

I started Spark from within IntelliJ Scala Console as local mode. The INFO shows

```
...
15/11/12 14:04:51 INFO SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://10.184.140.204:4040
...
```

Since I started it in local mode, why is the address not 127.0.0.1 or localhost?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you would want it bound to your loopback rather than your local IP? I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082531/how-to-allow-tcp-connections-from-local-host-only which gives an example of doing so in C++, though I have no idea if Spark has an out-of-the-box configuration method to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force the Spark UI to listen on 127.0.0.1 by setting `SPARK_LOCAL_IP` to that value.

Since the normal mode of operation for Spark is to be a distributed app, it tries to bind to a public IP address. There's not much sense in adding code to avoid that when running in local mode, since it still works.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This seems to be my case. I am creating a SparkContext on my laptop and I am currently on a university network. That's why Spark picks up the address in a private network 10.XXX.XXX.XXX. So I could expect that the Spark UI would be 127.0.0.1:4040 once I cut my network connection, right?

Comment: If the only interface available is 127.0.0.1, Spark will use that, yes.

Answer (score -2):

I assume that the Spark code is finding the current host name associated with the machine you're running and resolving that to an IP, which results in what you're seeing.

You can, however, tell spark to listen on a particular host name. You can specify the `-h` argument to both `start-master.sh` and `start-slave.sh` as specified [in the documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html)

You can also adjust the `SPARK_MASTER_IP` environment variable to tell Spark to use a different IP address.

Comment: He's talking about a Spark application, not the master or worker daemons.

Comment: It's all about spark application not standalone cluster.